# How to mark classes as Obsolete on UML

Tags: uml, class-diagram, obsolete

I have a few classes on my UML diagram which should not be used, but still available. 
Is there any way to mark these classes as obsolete?

I've seen <> notation somewhere, but can not find how to use it in MS Visio 2003.

And another question. Should these classes be on UML diagram at all? I can imagine answer on this question would be on "per case" basis, but I'm interested in hearing general opinions. And if you put obsolete classes on your UML diagrams, why you did it? or why not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you mean by " should not be used, but still available.". If they need to stay in the diagram but you want to visualize that they are now obsolete you can create a new stereotype <> and use it to annotate the obsolete classes.

If you don't really need them in the diagram then use a version control system for models as duffymo suggested. A list of version control tools for modeling elements can be founde [here](http://modeling-languages.com/version-control-tools-modeling-artifacts/)

Answer (score 2):

I think if you're going to take the time to update the UML, the best idea is to remove it from the model.  Leaving a bunch of "obsolete" diagram elements hanging around makes as much sense as keeping commented code in a version control system.  Let the version control system manage the history.

Comment: hm.. the class diagram is not under version control. Maybe I should put it there. Good idea!

Comment: Maybe.  All artifacts that can't be generated should be under version control.  The real question should be "Who cares about UML?"

Comment: that was my exact reasoning when I did not put it under VC -))

Answer (score 1):

I think that your model should include all your project and then you extract views from your model. If a class is not having any value in a specific view then this class should be removed from your class diagram view diagram but not from your model.

If you want to keep this class in your diagram then you can add a small comment (usually yellow square) or change the color of the class. I usually use green for class and then change the color to grey/green almost invisible but still visible color for non strategic classes.

Hope this help.